# Выполнить циклический сдвиг матрицы

Tags: java

> Ввести с консоли n – размерность матрицы a[n][n]. Задать значения элементов матрицы в интервале значений от -n до n с помощью датчика случайных чисел. Выполнить циклический сдвиг заданной матрицы на k позиций вправо(влево, вверх, вниз).

Comment: @vampirsha, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @vampirsha может вы смените манеру подачи вопроса на более подобающую? Слуг у вас здесь нет, что это за приказной тон такой - "выполнить", "ввести", "задать"? И вообще, вы сами-то хоть что-то пробовали сделать?

Comment: это называется работа за автора, ищите другие сайты и людей, которые будут бесплатно работать за вас или просто откройте справочник, попробуйте сами написать и если что-то не получается пишите тогда сюда

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если мне не изменяет память эта операция эквивалентна простому умножению исходной матрицы на специально подобраную наддиагональную матрицу в зависимости от направления сдвига и количества позиций. 
Читайте страницу 25 православного мануала Гантмахер Ф.Р. Теория матриц.

Ориентация сдвига(вверх-вниз или влево-вправо) выбирается исходя из порядка следования исходной и наддиангональной матрицы при умножении

Направление сдвига(вверх или вниз, влево или вправо) определяется видом наддиагональной матрицы

Количество позиций сдвига равно сдвигу единичной наддиагонали относительно главной диагонали подобранной матрицы

Вверх-вниз:

```
0 1 0 0   1 2 3 4      2 3 4 5
0 0 1 0 * 2 3 4 5   =  2 3 4 5
0 0 0 1   2 3 4 5      2 3 3 2
0 0 0 0   2 3 3 2      0 0 0 0
```

Влево-вправо:

```
 1 2 3 4   0 1 0 0     0 1 2 3
 2 3 4 5 * 0 0 1 0  =  0 2 3 4
 2 3 4 5   0 0 0 1     0 2 3 4
 2 3 3 2   0 0 0 0     0 2 3 3
```

Comment: Чтобы получился _циклический_ сдвиг, надо бы единичку внизу дописать:

    0 1 0 0
    0 0 1 0
    0 0 0 1
    1 0 0 0

Comment: Верно дело, перефразируя крылатую фразу, матрица - друг программиста.

Comment: А по времени это сколько займет? 

Тупой циклический сдвиг на 1 очевидно n\*n, а умножение матриц (просто не помню, как их умножают)?

Comment: n*n правда обычную формулу для умножения наверянка можно улучшить так как там много нулей в матрице